# Display product variation price without html tags

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I want to increase product variation price by some percentage but when i try to get variation product value it comes with html code but i need integer value.

```
function woocommerce_variable_add_to_cart() {
    global $product, $post;
    $variations = $product->get_available_variations();
    foreach ($variations as $key => $value) {
       echo $value['price_html'];
    }
 }
```

Comment: Do you want to convert string to integer ?

Comment: <span class="price"><del><span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">₨</span>120.00</span></del> <ins><span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">₨</span>111.00</span></ins></span>

I am getting above result i need Rs. 111.00 and Rs. 120 numbers not html tags. I need to multiply or devide them.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to get the price with this `display_price` I think:

```
function woocommerce_variable_add_to_cart() {
    global $product, $post;
    $variations = $product->get_available_variations();
    foreach ($variations as $key => $value) {
        echo $value['display_price'];
    }
 }
```

There is also a `$value['display_regular_price']` available, which is the original price if a price is reduced in some way.

Comment: I wanted to display variant prices.

Comment: Finally i used woocommerce dynamic pricing and discounts plugin to achieve discounts and prices without html tags.